# C++ structs, difference between new type; and new type()

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, new-operator

for example I have in C++ a struct like

```
typedef struct point {
    double x, y;
};
```

I can use

```
point *p = new point;
```

or

```
point *p = new point();
```

To create a point dynamically.

Whats the difference? In the second case x and y are initialized implicit to zero. Why not in the first case?

Answer (score 4):

According to the C++ Standard (11.6 Initializers)

> 11 An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e.,
>   (), shall be value-initialized.

It means that data members of the structure of scalar types are zero-initialized in this statement

```
point *p = new point();
```

In this case

```
point *p = new point;
```

the members of the structure are default initialized that is (as the class has no  user-defined constructor and the data members do not have initializers in the class definition) have indeterminate values.

Pay attention to that you could define the structure the following way

```
typedef struct point {
    double x = 0, y = 0;
};
```

In this case the result of the both statements above will be the same.